# Changing name package to previous version

Tags: java, android

Strange problem, my package was:

```
com.myname.myappname
```

after change is:

```
com.myname.myappname.abc
```

and now I cant back to previous name because when I'm going to rename I can change only end of package "abc" and it is not possible to leave this empty field.

so how to set my package to first edition ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it manually by moving all the files in abc package to parent package & then changing package path in all the files, time consuming but it will work.